# TextAllCaps in Text() widget of Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, capitalization

As we are having `android:textAllCaps="true"` feature in Android's Textview, how can we give this same feature in ***Text()*** Widget of Flutter?

I know `Text('Abc'.toUpperCase())`, is one way but I don't want to do it manually. Is there any property of Text() widget that converts it automatically or any widget that has similar property?

Comment: Text('Wow'.toUpperCase())

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22695

Comment: by this we are manually converting the string to uppercase, Is there any property of text which converts it automatically or any widget which property and is similar as Text()?

Comment: Sorry `Text` doesn't allow that however there is `TextField` aka `EditText` in Android, which has capitalisation property.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad thanks for sharing it, but that answer does not work.

Comment: Yes, that's not the answer, I just wanted to let you know there is no way of doing it in `Text`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Eugene nothing is wrong I am finding a shorter and common way by which we can make a common Text() widget for all.

Answer (score 21):

(EDITED) My solution is like this:

```
Text("apple".toUpperCase())
```

```
Returns:

APPLE
```

Comment: textAllCaps property in android xml converts all the text to capital letter not the first one.

Comment: Wrong answer, capitalizes only first letter of the word.

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use following function for the First word as Caps

```
String getCapitalizeString({String str}) {
    if (str.length <= 1) { return str.toUpperCase(); }
    return '${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.substring(1)}';
}
```

Use :

```
Text(this.getCapitalizeString(str: listObj[position]);
```

Comment: Seems that OP provided the best approach so far in his original question: just use `Text('Abc'.toUpperCase())`

Comment: That isn't what the question asked for it asked how to make the entire word capitalized.

Comment: Wrong answer, capitalizes only first letter of the word.

Comment: Seem question changed, and @campovski already mention in first line First word as Caps.

Answer (score 0):

To capitalize the text like this: "this is only a example" to this "This Is Only A Example",

use this function:

```
firstCharacterUpper(String text) {
    List arrayPieces = List();

    String outPut = '';

    text = 'this is only a example'; // This is not necessary, is only for the example. The text here is that one is passed in parameter.

    text.split(' ').forEach((sepparetedWord) {
      arrayPieces.add(sepparetedWord);
    });

    arrayPieces.forEach((word) {
      word =
          "${word[0].toString().toUpperCase()}${word.toString().substring(1)} ";
      outPut += word;
    });

    return outPut;
}
```

OutPut: 'This Is Only A Example'.

Comment: Wrong answer, capitalizes only first letter of the word.

Comment: @campovski 
Maybe your text has only one word.

Comment: I guess you meant my words only have one letter ...

Answer (score -1):

just to simplify the function of the answers before

```
String getCapitalizeString(String str) {
  String cRet = '';
  str.split(' ').forEach((word) {
    cRet += "${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.substring(1).toLowerCase()} ";
  });
  return cRet.trim();
}
```

Comment: The question asked about making the entire word capitalized not just the first letter.

Comment: Wrong answer, capitalizes only first letter of the word.